# Can i display column name when copying to excel? SP

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Short morning question..

When i copy the results from my stored procedure into excel or whatever it would be terrific to get the column names (50+columns).

Is it any easy way to do that?

Edit: I have both Navicat Premium and SSMS..

Comment: I assume you mean column names?

Comment: aye mister that is edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSMS, in the results grid, select whatever cells you want to copy (presumably All in your case), then right-click and select "Copy With Headers" (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).